# Writing a WATIR locator, when parent <div> is unique and child at bottom is identical to many others

Tags: html, dom, rspec, watir

There are so many `<p>` tags of same type. This `<p>` lie in unique type of `<div>`.

1. So I want to locate a `<p>` in attachment/reference of specific `<div>`.

   I don't want to write a `xpath`. It should be WATIR element, example:

   ```
   text_field(:comment_box){form_element(:class=>'commentform').div_element.div_element.textarea}
   ```
2. This specific `<div>` has so many `<div>` child(children) and last one is `<p>` tag.
   So I want to write something like

   ```
   p(:my_locator){div_element(:class=>'unique_parent_class')
   ```

   which contains `p(:class=>'write here')}`

I want to avoid long locators like

```
p(:my_locator){div_element(:class=>'unique_parent_class').div[2].fieldset.div.div[3].div[1].div.p(:class=>'write here')}`
```

Comment: I think you would be better off showing the HTML rather than an xpath. The xpath does not give as much detail about the structure of the HTML. For example, is there just 1 `<p>` tag in the unique div?

Comment: As an aside, I think you are mixing up Watir vs the Page-Object gem. It looks like you are trying to use a page-object accessor, but then mixing page-object and Watir methods in the block. This is going to give you a bunch of deprecation errors. As well, since the page-object locator API is some what a subset of what is allowed in Watir, you want to make sure you ask for the right one.

Comment: Oh Yes I am getting those and how I might(unknowingly) be doing that.

Comment: @JustinKo HTML added.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `<p>` tag is the only one within the `<div>` tag. Therefore, you can simply get the first nested `<p>` tag:

```
p(:file_field) { div_element(class: 'is-active').paragraph_element }
```